Remove ISP's default advert page from my naked domain
I registered a domain with some ISP. When navigating to www.example.com I'm shown a typical browser error, because that subdomain does not exist (e.g. in Firefox: "Server Not Found" ... "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site").
However, when navigating to example.com I'm shown the ISP's default landing page, which is an "under construction" advert for that company. I don't want that. This domain is for emails only, and I want a browser error for the naked domain too.
The domain has no hosting capabilities, so I can't host a blank page; I need a DNS-based solution.
Can I add/edit something in the zone file to make requests to the naked domain show a browser error, just like for the non-existent www subdomain?

The zone file had default A and AAAA records, which I deleted.
Now navigating to the naked domain shows a routing error, as desired.

Please accept this answer as correct

@JohnConde System says I must wait two days before accepting my own answer.
